# SVG-based text input field

Tags: javascript, user-interface, svg

Has anyone seen any javascript implementation of a text input field besides http://www.carto.net/papers/svg/gui/textbox/ ?

Comment: Why? What's wrong with that one?  **EDIT** After trying it out, I retract that question.  It's got a variety of flaws, including a complete lack of shortcut keys, bidi, and imperfect keyboard selection.

Comment: You asked this question in 2010. Now it's 2014. Is there a direct capability built within SVG at this point of time? Otherwise I hope there will be a possibility for SVG text to take user input in the very near future. It will be extremely helpful. I mean it could be just a matter of accessing the xml editor of the correct element and node on the go, wouldn't it?

Comment: SVG now allows HTML code through `foreignObject` which can include things like input boxes. Internet Explorer does not support this. See my answer below.

Comment: The link given in the question is broken.

Answer (score 42):

There is an interesting SVG node called `foreignObject`, which allows you to place HTML, flash, etc within your SVG code. Try the following:

```
<svg width="100%" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <foreignObject x="10" y="10" width="100" height="150">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <input>
    </div>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

**EDIT:** added `xmlns` so it works for IE.

Comment: @MarkKuczmarski, I forgot to add `xmlns` which [is apparently](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dn806280(v=vs.60)) required for IE. Can you test it now please? (I don't use Windows.)

Answer (score 10):

This is for MS Internet Explorer, not tested in any other browser.

As mentioned in another comment, up to IE11 does not support foreignObject.
Instead, use the contentEditable attribute.

### Plain SVG example

```
<svg width="100" height="100" >
    <g transform="translate(40,40)">
        <text contentEditable="true">foo</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

### D3.js example with data binding

Here we listen for key events to write the text back to the data.

```
selection.
  .append("text")
    .attr("contentEditable", true)
    .text(function(d) { return d.text })
    .on("keyup", function(d) { d.text = d3.select(this).text(); });
```

**Note**: If nodes are dynamically generated like with d3.js, you **must** capitalize `contentEditable`like such (this took me some time)!

**Note**: Do not style your text with `pointer-events: None`, for then you cannot interact with the text anymore, regardless of the contentEditable setting.

Comment: could you please post a fiddle

Comment: This did not work for me either. I don't know what is wrong. A fiddle might be really useful.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable

"Method of making any HTML element editable." Note the HTML in that quote.

Comment: I don't think this works for arbitrary browsers.  A shame, really.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen [another one](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/presentations/svgdemos/spiral-editfield.svg), note that it requires support for the ['editable' attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/text.html#text-edit) from SVG Tiny 1.2... it's definately more native in the sense that there's not a single line of javascript in that example. Try it out in [Opera](http://www.opera.com/download).

Comment: I am familiar with the editable attribute. Too bad 1.2 isn't really an option. Thanks anyway!