# Is it possible to mix HTML form input tags with SVG, or to use SVG to lay out a form?

Tags: html, jquery, svg, knockout.js

We like using jQuery templates with SVG for example to show a Product with a nicely styled price.

Say we have an SVG that represents a complicated layout. Is it possible to have the `<input>` tags nested in the SVG and still work within HTML 5? Are there alternatives within SVG to input data from the user, maybe extracting them with Knockout.js?

I know you could use the SVG in the sense of a background graphic and hack the positions so that the form fields line up. I am really interested in having the input statements flowed by the SVG if possible.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use [foreignObject](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/extend.html#EmbeddingForeignObjects). A small example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<svg xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
    <rect x="25" y="25" width="250" height="200" fill="#ff0000" stroke="#000000"/>
    <foreignObject x="50" y="50" width="200" height="150">
        <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <form>
                <input type="text"/>
                <input type="text"/>
            </form>
        </body>
    </foreignObject>
    <circle cx="60" cy="80" r="30" fill="#00ff00" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
</svg>
```

This is a standard SVG, but I added HTML elements between the rect and the circle using the foreignObject tag. The stack order is respected, the circle being in front of the inputs.

Other solutions exists in "pure" SVG, but they heavily rely on JavaScript. Here an example : http://www.carto.net/papers/svg/gui/textbox/

Comment: I get the two input boxes drawn, but I cannot enter any text. Any idea why? (Chrome 23/Ubuntu 11)

Comment: @Dan I can input without any problem in Google Chrome 26 and Firefox 19, Arch Linux.

Comment: If you attempt this, be aware of the long outstanding Chrome/Webkit bug reported here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=116566

Comment: Answer should state that foreignObject is not working up to IE11. See my workaround in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176146