# Can I use HTML tags inside an SVG tag?

Tags: html, text, svg, dojo

I'd like to use regular HTML tags (for instance an input tag) within an SVG tag.

Why? I would like my SVG graphic to be able to get text from the user (e.g., the user clicks on a box drawn with SVG and enters text on it), so I was thinkig about using HTML input tags within an SVG tag. Is this possible?

If the answer is no (which most probably will), how can I allow a user edit SVG text?

Comment: here is some topic about it, next time search little bit :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972705/is-it-possible-to-mix-html-form-input-tags-with-svg-or-to-use-svg-to-lay-out-a

Comment: ups, you're right, I didn't see that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already an answer to that question:

[how to change svg text tag using javascript innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282108/how-to-change-svg-text-tag-using-javascript-innerhtml)

But its not accepted.

It seems to be possible when you look at this example

http://starkravingfinkle.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2007/07/foreignobject-text.svg

from this source:

http://ajaxian.com/archives/foreignobject-hey-youve-got-html-in-my-svg

Comment: Looks great, the only problem that I see is that `foreignobject` [does not seem](http://schmerg.com/svg-support-in-ie9-close-but-should-try-harde) to be supported by IE9 :/

Comment: There are some applications out there that can convert html to svg, maybe you could use it. what exactly do you want to do ?

Comment: I'd like to display rich text (bullets, bold, italic) with floating images & videos

Comment: but why do you need svg for that ? why dont you do it using html

Comment: because this text should be in the middle of a rather complex graphic. The graphic could be done with CSS but I thought it would be easier to draw it using an SVG abstraction such as Dojo.gfx...

Comment: wouldnt it be possible to put the svg as the background of a div and a text-layer over the div ? To have a floating text, that seems to go around the svg, you could use transparent divs, that sketch the important areas in the svg, so that the floating text has to go around them...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27877/discussion-between-lucian-depold-and-mike)