# Text input fields in d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I want a simple text input field for my d3.js visualization, as simple as the HTML `<input>`. I'm surprised that I can't find any native svg elements for this. Is there any simpler way of achieving a text input field than a `<text>` element inside a `<rect>` which triggers a keylistener that updates the `text` attribute of the `<text>` element upon every keydown? Creating code for SHIFT, Alt, backspace, delete keys etc really seems like reinventing the wheel and I want to avoid it. Is there any way I can?

Comment: You can find something useful here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972705/is-it-possible-to-mix-html-form-input-tags-with-svg-or-to-use-svg-to-lay-out-a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless there are some other constraints which you haven't mentioned, it's perfectly possible to mix HTML and SVG in the same document. There's probably no need to reinvent a input field in SVG.