# how to have a text field in SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

I do not have much idea about SVG. I need to have a text field over SVG file. How to make it? Or can I have a text field within SVG file. I am using SVG file as `<img>` in my html code.  Can I have text field in SVG or in any other way.
This is my CSS file

```
  input[type="text"] {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  font-size: 115%;
 max-width:300%;
    float:right;
     width:40%;
    min-height:6.45%;

    position:absolute;
    left:2.68%;
    top:70%;
}

#textbox{
max-width:300%;
    float:right;
     width:20%;
    min-height:6.45%;

    position:absolute;
    left:1.70%;
    top:70%;
    z-index:1;

}
```

This is my HTML file

```
 <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="textbox">
    <input type="text"/>
    </div>
    <img src="samp.svg"/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Can someone help me code?

Comment: You definitelly can have text in SVG. Have a look here http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_text.asp

Comment: i need a text area not default text

Comment: You have not wrapped the SVG and textbox both inside the container. Move the svg file inside the `textbox` div.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to mix HTML form input tags with SVG, or to use SVG to lay out a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972705/is-it-possible-to-mix-html-form-input-tags-with-svg-or-to-use-svg-to-lay-out-a)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the two elements in a parent container and then you can position it absolutely to the relatively positioned parent element. Change the dimensions and position values according to your need.

```css
.input-svg {
  position: relative;
}
input[type="text"] {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  font-size: 115%;
  height: 5%;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 0;
  left: 27.5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-svg">
  <input type="text">
  <img src="http://svgporn.com/logos/angular-icon.svg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, you will need to adjust them and use percentage values.

Comment: even after i try this but it do not work fine for me

Comment: Can you post your code that you tried for responsiveness?

Comment: You have not wrapped the SVG and textbox both inside the container?