# how to draw text box in raphael.js?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am using Raphael.js library in my application.I want to know that how to draw text-box on canvas using raphael.js library,so that user can input the values in the text-box dynamically.

Comment: paper.text(),but is used for drawing text on canvas not for drawing text-box.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [documentation](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html) ? There are no features to 'draw' a text-box using raphaeljs. However, if you are interested in SVG-based inputs you can checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176146/svg-based-text-input-field) question, there are some very interesting answers there.