# input field inside nested svg group 'g'

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, canvas

I'm trying to make a dynamic program that makes use of SVG, those SVG's are stacked inside a nested group of SVG's to handle functions on those elements. I found out how to add shapes like a circle, rectangle, eclipse, and a square but now I'm trying to add a text field so the end-user can import text to the canvas. I tried to add it to the svg>g tag directly but then it doesn't show up.

this one is used to add start the function so it triggers the action of making the element.

```html
<div class="title" id="text">Text</div>
```

after clicking on the tag it goes to this to start the process (its a snippet but this part works fine)

```js
let mytext = document.getElementById('text');
mytext.addEventListener('click', function() {
    eltype = 5;
    layerArray.unshift(new Element(canvas.canvas, {
        left: 1050,
        top: 1050
    }, eltype));
    console.log(layerArray);
    this.layeropzet = new Layer(this, layerArray);
}, false);
```

then it goes here this makes the 2 nested groups so I can add shapes in 2 different layers

```js
var ecl = document.createElementNS(canvas.namespaceURI, "g");
ecl.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "Removeable")
var el = document.createElementNS(canvas.namespaceURI, "g");
```

here is where the fun starts **this is where I'm my eye it goes wrong**

```js
let t = document.createElement("input");
t.setAttributeNS(null, "type", "text");
t.setAttributeNS(null, "text", "here comes your text");
t.setAttributeNS(null, "backgroundColor", "C4C4C4")
t.setAttributeNS(null, "border", "3px dotted white");
t.setAttributeNS(null, "name", "mytext");
```

after making the input field it goes to some append statements to get it on the canvas

```js
el.append(t);
ecl.append(el);
this.ecl = ecl;

//put in on canvas
canvas.append(this.ecl);
this.canvas = canvas;
```

after all of this, the SVG shapes work just fine but the input tag gets added to the HTML doc but is nowhere to see on the canvas

**Screenshots:**

Normal shape

[image: circle SVG shape]

Input text

[image: the input field]

- The orange rectangle temporarily for moving and the blue one for rotation.

Comment: If you're trying to add an input to an SVG element I don't think you can.  Have a look at this link - it may help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176146/svg-based-text-input-field

Comment: input (and other html) elements would need to be children of foreignObject elements in SVG